# Disabling Specific Vue Warnings on Specific Files

Tags: vue.js

On the app I am working on, I am getting this warning:

```
[Vue warn]: Duplicate keys detected: '-'. This may cause an update error
```

This is something I can't avoid since it is how our objects are structured.

So is there any way I can disable this warning on a specific Vue file?

I have seen `silent` Vue config (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#silent) but this disables all the warnings. And there is also the `warnHandler` (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#warnHandler) but this is only for the dev mode so the warnings will still be displayed when on prod mode. I want it also disabled on prod mode.

Anyone has any idea?

Thanks!